# Questions about creating circular UIImageView using rectangular image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Now I'd like to create a circular image view, and when I apply different-shaped(like rectangular) images to it, it can still keep circular shape. After googling, I have the following code:

```
self.avatarImageView = ({
    UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueRoundRect"];
    imageView.alpha = 1.0;
    imageView;
});
[self.view addSubview:self.avatarImageView];

[self.avatarImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
    make.top.equalTo(self.loginButton.mas_bottom);
    make.width.equalTo(@(2 * avatarImageViewRadius));
    make.height.equalTo(@(2 * avatarImageViewRadius));
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.mas_centerX);
}];
self.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = avatarImageViewRadius;    //Create a circular avatar imageView.
self.avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

The code is written in `viewDidLoad`, and as you can see, I do auto layout with the help of [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry). But when I run the app, the imageView is still rectangular, but the image shape seems to change from rectangular to rounded-rectangular(The original image I use is a rectangular blue image).Any ideas?
[image: The result from the view hierarchy debugger]

If I create a new class AvatarImageView and put the following code into it:

```
- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    self = [super initWithImage:image];

    if (self)
    {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.image = image;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

And within the view controller's `viewDidLoad` I write:

```
self.avatarImageView = [[BBTAvatarImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueRoundRect"]];
[self.view addSubview:self.avatarImageView];
[self.avatarImageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make){
    make.top.equalTo(self.loginButton.mas_bottom);
    make.width.equalTo(@(2 * avatarImageViewRadius));
    make.height.equalTo(@(2 * avatarImageViewRadius));
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.mas_centerX);
}];
```

But the result it the same as before.

Comment: Your image view (`avatarImageView`) seems to be larger than container view (`self.view`), so it is cropped. Try to increase container size or decrease `avatarImageViewRadius`.

Comment: The screenshot is simply the imageView, the gray frame is not the bound of `self.view` but `self.avatarImageView`

Comment: And how exactly you get that gray frame? Is there some code which sets border color on imageView's layer, or whatever?

Comment: No this is the screenshot from view debugger, it will automatically add a frame.

Comment: Oh, I think I've got it. Your original square image is *smaller* than imageView, so it gets centered. Set imageView's content mode to stretch/scale to fill, so it takes the entire image view.

Comment: Well I just figured it out, it's because of the white border around the image I use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a circle by taking a square and applying rounded corners to it, with the corner radius being equal to 1/2 the length of a side.

You can't get an oval shape from a rectangle with rounded corners unless you can round the corners in a non-circular shape, and Apple no longer supports that. You'd have to build the corner shapes yourself.

If you try to set up your circle shape in viewDidLoad it likely won't work. In viewDidLoad your view controller's views haven't been resized/layout adjusted for the current screen size and rotation. You want to calculate your dimensions and corner radius values in layoutSubviews.

Comment: I create a new `AvatarImageView` class and put the code that set its corner radius into method `layoutSubviews`, and within ViewController I create an instance of it, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Ah I figure it out when I set the background of `self.view` to blue. It turns out that it's due to the white border around the image!

Answer (score 0):

This could help you to circular image

```
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.imageView setImage:image];
```